# SQL Query with aggregate function and group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: That is the required output. click for image]

My query is-
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9e89e/761

On average profit, the formula needs to group by aggregate function.So not getting required profit My query is attached above link and the required output is attached by image. please help me.

Comment: Please do not add random irrelevant product tags to your question!

Comment: I  thought it will reach multiple developers. Next time I will take care

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @anupamtiwari yes, your question reached more developers and then annoyed them as it had nothing to do with the product they know...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count of the different universe first using `count(*) over (partition by u.universe)` and after that you can apply your logic to calculate `profit` like the following query.

```
select c.id,c.name,u.universe,u.budget,u.revenue
    ,(revenue - budget) / count(*) over (partition by u.universe) as profit
from universe u
inner join characters c on u.id = c.universe_id
order by u.universe desc
```

Check the updated fiddle [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9e89e/791)

Comment: You don't need a subquery for this. You can divide by `count(*) over (...)` directly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, you are right,  thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my answer.